# Hard disk image files don't upload to OneDrive

Tags: onedrive, cloud-storage, imaging

I would like to store my hard drive images in the cloud, so that they are not at risk if the local PC breaks down.

However, OneDrive (using the desktop client for Windows) does not upload the images. They are in *.adi format and are between 4 GB and 50 GB in size.

As a test, I zipped one of the smaller images with encryption, but this doesn't get uploaded either.

The file sizes should not be a problem, as the [size limit is now 250 GB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restrictions-and-limitations-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa#individualfilesize).

All other files are synchronized flawlessly. The image files are also not open anywhere else. The path looks something like this

```
D:\OneDrive\Backup Images\XYZ-SystemBackup-B\Win10C\Win10B2.7z
```

As I have read in various places and unfortunately followed, I just now disconnected my OneDrive account from the OneDrive client and then reconnected it, pointing it to the locally still present OneDrive folder again.

Although there is identical data locally and online, the OneDrive client now **uploads** all data again to an extent of 280 GB ‍♂️
(which number however includes the size of the image files).

This is on a private OneDrive account that comes with the Office 365 subscription.

I just moved two of the image files, one in original format and the other one zipped, to my business OneDrive folder. There, the image files immediately started getting uploaded.

**Edit:** Ah! Now I have enabled Files On-Demand:
[image: OneDrive Files On-Demand]

...and then selected "Free up space" by right clicking on the OneDrive folder. Now the image files are uploaded!

Comment: How are you uploading the files?

Comment: In theory the file size limit is 250GB (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restrictions-and-limitations-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa#individualfilesize) so it shouldn't be that. As harrymc asks, how are you uploading the file? Are you uploading via web browser or using the desktop client?

Comment: Am using the desktop client.

Comment: I just created a random 30GB file (should be the same as an encrypted file as far as OneDrive is concerned) and it quite happily starts uploading it. Are you able to upload other files? What happens if you rename it? Do you still have the file open in a program? Where *exactly* are you putting the file to be uploaded?

Comment: I suggest you try to upload some imges via OneDrive online. If you are usning OneDrive for Business, please make sure the format of the imges are not blocked to uploaded.

Comment: I have added answers to your questions as well as more details in the OP.